# input type number value from query does not work while choosing type text is (almost) ok

Tags: php, sql, forms, numbers

I have an input value loading query which seems ok while the type declaration is text but does not work using number, that’s the text:

```
<label>Input Label</label>
<input type="number" value="<?php include "dbconfig.php"; $result = $conn->query("select column FROM table ORDER BY column ASC"); while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {$variableNUMBER = $row['contesto'];} echo ++$variableNUMBER;   mysqli_close($conn);?>"/>
```

Also, using text it mysteriously add 3 blank spaces in the value and this is maybe a problem for the number input type. 
I thought those spaces are related to some other command but the only echo here is the variableNUMBER one and, running the script outside the field, it seems fine giving not that problem.

Beside, my aim was to use MAX(DISTINCT expression) query but was not really able to make it fine.

Some one have any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: You want the highest value of `contesto`?

Comment: The database type is text or char? They are padded with spaces. I think that's what you are referring to perhaps? And if you post your SQL query and any error you are getting that will help.

Comment: @JacobH my column in the SQL DB is int(11) but there are no error executing the query, as I've wrote is ok using type="text" for the input - except those 2 blank spaces in front if the value (yes, typo error before: there only are 2 spaces and the value)

Comment: So I think your problem is using the text type, which is probably not giving you the max value you want. Can you edit the post and add the expected results of your SQL query?

Comment: @HarveyFletcher basically it is so: higher number in that DB column - which is a  int(11) type and make it correctly save the numbers even if they came from the input using type text and has 2 blank spaces in front of the value (in the db field there are no spaces at all - neither the previous number nor the one I save)

Comment: @JacobH I do get the higher number and it is automatically increased by one, as a matter of fact that script functionally do exactly what I want. Is that seems me quite raw and was wondering how to improve it's compliance to programming guidelines

Comment: From the SQL side, `SELECT MAX(DISTINCT...)...` is a pretty standard query. If you are looking to get the maximum distinct value from column, that's most likely just fine. So if the query is returning the data you want, I would say go with it.

Comment: @JacobH I'll try that and - if will have time enough to perform it before the question will be closed - I'll let you know. Thanks for your suggestion ;)